# SEAM 2 with CAS Client 3

Tags: seam, cas

Hi i wounder if anyone know of any guide for  SEAM 2 and CAS client 3 or newer out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this 
http://myjavaroom.blogspot.com/2009/11/cas-single-sign-on-and-jboss-seam.html